# Cannot receive message from server through socket android

Tags: android, sockets

I've writen a function to send and receive message from server like this:

```
//Send mess to server through socket
public boolean send_Message_service(String mess) throws IOException{
    Log.i("debug", "Connection status: "+String.valueOf(this.clientSocket.isBound()));
    boolean rs=false;
    //Send mess toi server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream())), true);
    out.println(mess);      
    //Receive mess from server

    String mess_From_Server=in.readLine();

    if(mess_From_Server.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
        rs=true;
    }
    else{
        rs=false;
    }

    return rs;
}
```

That function can send message to server but cannot receive message from server, when I run it with my phone, it's take a long time and Force Close!

Here is the logcat:

```
10-11 12:17:35.201: INFO/global(279): Default buffer size used in BufferedWriter constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
10-11 12:21:26.321: DEBUG/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

And here is code of server (run on Java not Android):

```
int receiveMsgSize;//Size of received message
    byte[] receiveBuf= new byte[100]; //Receive Buffer
try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new  ObjectOutputStream(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    InputStream in;
        in = this.clientSocket.getInputStream();

        while((receiveMsgSize=in.read(receiveBuf))!=-1){

            String mess=new String(receiveBuf,0,receiveMsgSize);
            System.out.println(mess.length());
            System.out.println(mess);                                           
            }                                                               
            oos.writeObject("success");
        }                           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: "It's not work": insufficent information. Define "not work". What happens instead?

Comment: 'Force Close!' is insufficient information as well. What does it mean? and what does the server code look like? You're supposed to post complete verbatim error messages, stack traces etc, rather than just paraphrase them or post what you think is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your server sends the response via ObjectOutputStream.writeObject.
2. Your client reads the response via BufferedReader.readLine().

This is never going to work.

If you have an ObjectOutputStream at one end you must have an ObjectInputStream at the other end.

If you have writeObject() at one end you must have readObject() at the other end.

If you have writeXXX() at one end you must have readXXX() at the other end, for all XXX that I can think of.

Or conversely if you have BufferedReader.readLine() at one end you must have BufferedWriter.write() followed by BufferedWriter.newLine() at the other end.

Don't use PrintStream or PrintWriter over a network, as they swallow exceptions you need to know about.

Comment: I understand what you say :) Thanks for the support, I'll try to edit my code and feedback soon!

Comment: I've edited my client use 
ObjectInputStream in2= new ObjectInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());

String mess_From_Server=in2.readLine(); //But it still don't work :(

Comment: It's working, just use 
String mess_From_Server = (String)in2.readObject();

Comment: @Han Tran It's working, just use readObject() when you write objects with writeObject(), or readLine() when you write lines, etc, as I already said in my answer.